# how to submit value to another page without using form tag [JAVASCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, submit

Hii Everyone can help me ? How to submit value to another page without using form tag (method=post), so only using javascript.

```
function runScript(e) {
   if(e.keyCode==13){
      var text=document.getElementById('edtsearch').value
      // bla bla must be filled with function to submit value
   }
   return false
}
```

Comment: That depends on the other page. If it allows it, you might be able to use Ajax (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). If not, then a form element is probably the way to go. It doesn't have to exist in the HTML (thus you don't have to use a form tag), you can dynamically create the element. You will probably get more helpful answers if you provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery library:

You can use jquery POST request.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

WITHOUT LIBRARY, JUST PLAIN JAVASCRIPT.

```
window.location = "http://www.page.com"; //this get another page

form=document.getElementById('formName'); //this fills the form
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='whatever.html';
        form.submit();
        form.action='whatever.html';
        form.target='';
```

Comment: I have value as parameter, how to submit value to parameter data ? do you have example ?

Comment: Note that if the "other page" is an external site, then an Ajax call probably won't work. Also the OP didn't mention jQuery, please provide a solution not using any libraries.

Comment: hii Felix, I have added some code, you can see it, I want to redirect to internal page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal AJAX implementation in pure JS:

```
function ajaxRequest(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    function ajaxResponse(){
        try {
            if(hr.readyState === 4){
                if(hr.status === 200){
                    // do something with hr.responseText
                } else {
                    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
                }
            }
        } catch(er){}
    }

    hr.onreadystatechange = ajaxResponse;
    hr.open('post', 'http://targeturl.com/targetfile.php'); 
    hr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    hr.send('variable1=value1&variable2=value2&variable3=value3');
}
```

And on the server in targetfile.php:

```
$response = '';
$var1 = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['variable1'] ) ) {
    $var1 = $_POST['variable1'];
}
$var2 = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['variable2'] ) ) {
    $var1 = $_POST['variable2'];
}
$var3 = '';
if ( !empty( $_POST['variable3'] ) ) {
    $var1 = $_POST['variable3'];
}
// do something
echo $response;
exit;
```

And here is a resource that will explain what this actually is (highly recommended reading): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started